# Why does it keep saying that the function Split does not exist?

Tags: ruby

```
x = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
#=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

x.split(", ")
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:Array
```

Comment: Because it doesn't. Do you mean to use `join(', ')`?

Comment: x is an array. Arrays don't need splitting.

Comment: What is your expected result? What should `["1", "2", "3", "4"].split(", ")` return?

Answer (score 2):

The `String#split` method in ruby is used to divide a string into substrings

```
'a,b,c,d'.split(',') # => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

You are trying to invoke `Array#split` (aka on an array object). As such array method doesn't exists, you get:

```
error undefined method split for ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:Array`
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't be split. You are probably thinking of splitting a string?

You will reach the desired value by simply x[0] for the 0 index, first object in the array.

This to any help?